# Examples to understand doublethink practice?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

While reading 1984, I stumbled upon the word **doublethink**. I have looked-up the definition of the word, However, I still don't understand what that means, as the definition is fairly complex.

I have checked out a few examples of doublethink on Internet, but I still think that I don't understand it completely.

Could somebody explain the word **doublethink** with examples? I feel like it is a very important word, and one of the central points of the novel.

Some examples of doublethink:

> War is Peace, Ignorance is Strength, Freedom is slavery.

Answer (score 2):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/doublethink) gives this definition:

> The acceptance of or mental capacity to accept contrary opinions or beliefs at the same time, especially as a result of political indoctrination.

This is actually quite hard to understand, so a [simpler definition](https://cfa.gmu.edu/news/2019-10/big-brother-and-other-terms-1984):

> the act of simultaneously accepting two mutually contradictory beliefs as correct

So in your example of "war is peace", emphasises the idea that society finds unity in hating an enemy, no matter who that enemy is. In fact, the paradox, or contradiction in terms, that comes along with changing the enemy constantly feeds into the idea that ignorance is strength. [Source](https://study.com/learn/lesson/war-is-peace-1984.html)

So basically this all combines into one idea that:

> One thing **is** another thing

Even if there are completely contradictory, e.g. peace is good and keeps the country from falling apart, war is bad and crushes a country.

Check this [website](https://study.com/learn/lesson/war-is-peace-1984.html) out! It gives in depth meanings for the quotes you gave.